# Invite workspace group email as optional?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google-groups

Months ago I recall (maybe incorrectly) that in Google Calendar with my Google Workspace account I was able to invite Workspace groups (a group with an email address) to events **and specify them as Optional**. I do not see how to do this now—hovering over the bust icon on the group now expands the entire group instead of letting me mark the group invitee as Optional.

I have full visibility into the group that I'd like to invite. Invite works fine normally, I just would like to mark the entire group members as Optional for the event.

Is there really no way to invite a group as optional to a event?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed directly to Google as a feature request.

Comment: @Rubén please unlock this. It's already been asked to Google but they're not accepting answers. It would be good to keep the discussion open here. See: https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/199845076/how-to-make-a-mark-a-group-as-optional-in-the-meeting-invite

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not how Web Applications Stack Exchange works. If you need more details, consider to ask a question about the our workings in [meta].

Comment: @Rubén I didn't see "Is a missing feature from [webapp] and should be directed to them instead" in that document you listed, so I can't really see your reasoning. If you try to do something in a web app and you can't, why is that discussion barred from this stackexchange? Seems counter productive.

Comment: What do you mean by "the document you listed"?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mark the entire group as optional. Although you can "Expand" the group, which makes them all individual invitees. **Then** you can mark them as optional, or even remove individual group members.

[image: ExpandGroup]

Comment: Yep, that I can do, but I really just want all group members to be optional—expanding them kind of defeats the purpose since you need to change them one by one, which is tedious for large meetings/groups. You also lose the group functionality, so for example updating the event you'd get new group members added automatically.

Comment: @notbrain You might have to make a feature request directly to Google.